# Set up wildfly as a service in OS X

Tags: java, macos, jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-9

How can I set up Wildfly 9 as service in OS X El Capitan as well as enable it to start up on boot and enable start,restart and stop commands like

```
sudo /usr/sbin/widlfy start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OS X` the de facto standard to start and execute a process at a specified time (eg. at startup, scheduled intervals, etc.) is to create a Launch Agent or Launch Daemon. Depending on task(s) you want to run should also be indicative of whether it's an agent or daemon.

↳ [Creating Launch Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html)